# ModuleNotFoundError in Django after installing the socail-auth-app

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-authentication

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'social django
```

The error keeps poping up when I tried to run migrate.

I Installed the `pip3 install social-auth-app-django` and everything was downloaded.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=(
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

I have also included the soical django in INSTALLED_APPS.

Is there anything wrong in this?

Comment: you activated your env before installation

Comment: yes, i did activate it

Comment: once you activated env dont have to use pip3, so uninstall and use pip to install again

Comment: uninstalled and reinstalled. nothing changed

Comment: check this link https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/23

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace please.